# Select parent name using parent id in the same table

Tags: sql, postgresql, hierarchical-data

I have a table with tag_categories which i'm joining with some other tables so i can get the category of a tag of a file, in that table i have a column parent_id which is just another tag category from the same table. While constructing the query like below it does retrieve the parent_id, i don't know how to get the parent name:

Query:

```
select 
    tags.id, 
    tags.name,
    tag_categories.name,
    tag_categories.parent_id,
    count(files.id) 
from 
    "files" 
    inner join "file_tags_join" on "files"."public_id" = "file_tags_join"."file_public_id" 
    inner join "tags" on "file_tags_join"."tag_id" = "tags"."id" 
    inner join "tag_categories" on "tags"."category_id" = "tag_categories"."id" 
where 
    "tags"."category_id" is not null 
group by 
    tags.id, 
    tags.name,
    tag_categories.name,
    tag_categories.parent_id
```

What I expect to get beside what I'm already getting, is the name of the category that match the category's parent_id:

```
id  name    name    parent_id   count   parent_name
2   tag2    tagCategory2    1   1         tagCategory1
1   tag1    tagCategory1    (null)  1     null
```

Here is the [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b6d1c/3):

Comment: share your sample output

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin, there is a sql fiddle link on the bottom

Comment: Fiddle is fine, but we should be able to read _this_ question and see your data, and be able to understand your problem.

Comment: The WHERE clause is redundant. (The JOIN condition will not pass any null values.)

Comment: @PetruLebada, what is your expected output

Comment: @fa06 , I've updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=cf5a183df304c3ebe24ea91b9c6dbc85)**

```
select 
    tags.id, 
    tags.name,
    tag_categories.name,
    tag_categories.parent_id,
    b.name as parentname,
    count(files.id) 
    from 
    "files" 
    inner join "file_tags_join" on "files"."public_id" = "file_tags_join"."file_public_id" 
    inner join "tags" on "file_tags_join"."tag_id" = "tags"."id" 
    inner join "tag_categories" on "tags"."category_id" = "tag_categories"."id" 
    left join  "tag_categories" b on tag_categories.parent_id = b.id
    where 
    "tags"."category_id" is not null 
    group by 
    tags.id, 
    tags.name,
    tag_categories.name,
    tag_categories.parent_id,b.name
```

OUTPUT:

```
id  name    name         parent_id  parentname  count
2   tag2    tagCategory2    1       tagCategory1    1
1   tag1    tagCategory1                            1
```